# Is it possible to track the smtp host by code in java?

Tags: java, smtp

I need that the application be able to track the smtp host by the email account, because it have to be capable to work with any mail account.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: what you mean by *tracking smtp host*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: no you can't.
To some degree you can get a smtp host from an email address, but not all email providers have an smtp server, and most email providers will require user specific authentication when using their smtp servers.

It's still possible to send mail from your computer when your email provider doesn't provide an smtp server because most Internet providers also provide you with an smtp server. You can't determine this smtp server based on someone's emailadres.

If your application always has to be able to send mail I would look into a free smtp server somewhere, or host your own.